# Return to Index page from detail with filters (EnumDropDownListFor) set MVC ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, indexing, enumdropdownlistfor

I am having an issue trying to return to my index (List) page with my filter set correctly. The filter is never set on return from the details page and always defaults to the first value in the drop down list. Using the Html helper EnumDropDownListFor.

**EDIT:** I should point out that if I change the current month filter from the index page that it posts correctly to the Index ActionResult and the filter is correctly set back in the Index page. So the issue is when posting from the details page back to the Index page only.

Here's my code.

### Model Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ShiftPatternConfigurator.Models
{
    // shift view
    public class ShiftViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Shift> Shifts { get; set; }
        public Month Month { get; set; }
    }

    // shift model
    public class Shift
    {
        public int ShiftNo;
        public string ShiftName;
        public DateTime StartTime;
        public DateTime FinishTime;
        public string Team;
        public int Week;
        public int CycleWeek = 0;
        public string StartDay;
        public DateTime StartDate;
    }

    // month enum
    public enum Month
    {
        January = 1,
        February = 2,
        March = 3,
        April = 4,
        May = 5,
        June = 6,
        July = 7,
        August = 8,
        September = 9,
        October = 10,
        November = 11,
        December = 12
    }
}
```

### Controller Code:

```
using ShiftPatternConfigurator.DataAccess;
using ShiftPatternConfigurator.Models;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ShiftPatternConfigurator.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Index
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Shift Pattern";
            ShiftViewModel monthShiftView = new ShiftViewModel
            {
                Month = new Month()
            };
            monthShiftView.Month = (Month)DateTime.Now.Month;
            monthShiftView.Shifts = DbContext.GetShiftsByMonth(monthShiftView.Month);       
            return View(monthShiftView);
        }

        // POST: Index
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Month month)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Shift Pattern";
            ShiftViewModel monthShiftView = new ShiftViewModel
            {
                Month = new Month()
            };
            monthShiftView.Month = month;
            monthShiftView.Shifts = DbContext.GetShiftsByMonth(monthShiftView.Month);
            return View(monthShiftView);
        }

        // GET: Details
        public ActionResult Details(int shiftNo, Month monthFilter)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Shift Details";
            ViewBag.MonthFilter = monthFilter;
            Shift shift = DbContext.GetShiftByShiftNo(shiftNo);
            return View(shift);
        }
    }
}
```

### Index (List) Code:

```
@model ShiftPatternConfigurator.Models.ShiftViewModel
<div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>@ViewBag.Title - @Model.Month</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Month)
        <input type="submit" value="Select Month" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
    }

</div>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Shift No</th>
        <th>Shift Name</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Finish Time</th>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Start Day</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @if (Model.Shifts.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.Shifts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ShiftNo</td>
                <td>@item.ShiftName</td>
                <td>@item.StartTime</td>
                <td>@item.FinishTime</td>
                <td>@item.Team</td>
                <td>@item.Week</td>
                <td>@item.StartDay</td>
                <td>@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { shiftNo = item.ShiftNo, monthFilter = Model.Month }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { shiftNo = item.ShiftNo, monthFilter = Model.Month }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" align="center"><h2>No Data</h2></td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

### Detail Code:

```
@using ShiftPatternConfigurator.Models
@model Shift

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Shift - @Model.ShiftNo</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Shift No:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.ShiftNo</dd>
        <dt>Shift Name</dt>
        <dd>@Model.ShiftName</dd>
        <dt>Start Time</dt>
        <dd>@Model.StartTime.ToShortDateString() @Model.StartTime.ToLongTimeString()</dd>
        <dt>Finish Time</dt>
        <dd>@Model.FinishTime.ToShortDateString() @Model.FinishTime.ToLongTimeString()</dd>
        <dt>Team:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.Team</dd>
        <dt>Week:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.Week</dd>
        <dt>Cycle Week:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.CycleWeek</dd>
        <dt>Start Day:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.StartDay</dd>
        <dt>Start Date:</dt>
        <dd>@Model.StartDate</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id = Model.PrimaryKey */ }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List-ActionLink", "Index", "Home", new { month = ViewBag.MonthFilter })
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("month", (Month)ViewBag.MonthFilter)
        <input type="submit" value="Back to List-Form" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
    }
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Back to List-Ajax", "Index", "Home",
        new { month = (Month)ViewBag.MonthFilter },
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" },
        new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })


</p>
```

I have tried the following ways to get back to my index page with the filter set:

1. **@Html.ActionLink method**

I have found that this will not work as ActionLink always sends a GET request so I cannot use this method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List-ActionLink", "Index", "Home", new { month = ViewBag.MonthFilter })
```

2. **@Ajax.ActionLink method**

Using the Ajax method the Index POST method gets hit but the page stays on the detail page.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Back to List-Ajax", "Index", "Home",
    new { month = (Month)ViewBag.MonthFilter },
    //new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "window.location.href = '/'" },
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" },
    new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
```

3. **@Html.BeginForm method**

With this method it posts correctly to the POST ActionResult correctly, however the drop down list defaults to the first in the list. So the filter is not passed correctly to the enumdropdownlistfor.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Hidden("month", (Month)ViewBag.MonthFilter)
    <input type="submit" value="Back to List-Form" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
}
```

Here is method 3 using @Html.BeginForm to post back, in screenshots with debugging values shown:

1. Page is launched and hits the GET index ActionResult, the Models Month enum is set to the current month and the list of shifts are returned from the BDcontext and assigned to the Model.

[image: GET Index ActionResult]

2. The Index view then renders the Html setting the EnumDropDownListFor to the currect date correctly

[image: Setting Enum DDL Correctly]

As you can see from the image the month is set to the current month.

[image: Correctly Set Month Filter]

**EDIT:** Here is the correctly generated HTML output by the @Html.EnumDropDownListFor helper

[image: Correctly Generated Select List]

3. After Selecting the details link, the code hits the GET details ActionResult and renders the view correctly.

[image: Details Code]
[image: Details View]

4. After hitting the back to List-Form button the POST Index Action Result is hit correctly setting all the parameters.

[image: Index Code POST]

5. But the view is rendered with the Month filter defaulting to the first in the list, not my selected month.

**EDIT:** Here is the incorrectly generated HTML output by the @Html.EnumDropDownListFor helper

[image: Incorrectly Generated Select List]

[image: Index View Code After Post]
[image: Index View Post Filter Failled]

Please help with suggestions how I can make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a work around for my issue, although it feels like it is a hack opposed to the correct way to do it. Maybe someone can comment as to why it didn't work the way I wanted it to?

What I did was the following:

1. Use ActionLink in my Detail page passing a parameter.
2. Handle the optional parameter in my GET Index ActionResult method.

So the code looks like this.

**Detail View Action Link:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Home", new { monthFilter = ViewBag.MonthFilter }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
```

**Index (List) GET ActionResult:**

```
// GET: Index
public ActionResult Index(string monthFilter)
{

    ViewBag.Title = "Shift Pattern";
    ShiftViewModel monthShiftView = new ShiftViewModel
    {
        Month = new Month()
    };

    // hack to fix issue with filter not being passed back to index page from Details view
    if(monthFilter == null)
        monthShiftView.Month = (Month)DateTime.Now.Month;
    else
        monthShiftView.Month = (Month)Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), monthFilter); ;

    monthShiftView.Shifts = DbContext.GetShiftsByMonth(monthShiftView.Month);       
    return View(monthShiftView);
}
```

So as you can see I handle the month value, by using the current month if the month value passed in is null or I use the value passed in if its available to be used.